# Почему компоненты в React перезаписывают себя?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю React, заметил, что последний `child-компонент` перезаписывает предыдущий.

В моем случае после рендеринга `<Feedback />` присутствует в DOM, а `<Header />` отсутствует.

Описания причины такого поведения найти не могу, не могли бы вы подсказать, как это исправить, и где это описано?

```
function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </header>
  );
}

function Feedback() {
  return (
    <ul></ul>
  );
}

function App() {
  return(
    <Header text="Отзывы" />,
    <Feedback />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Разве можно возвращать 2  элемента без родителя? Попробуйте обернуть app return в <></>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По [правилам React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) Вы можете вернуть только один элемент из метода render. Заверните Ваши компоненты, например в `div` или воспользуйтесь [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)'ом что бы сохранить оригинальную верстку:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>   
       <Header text="Отзывы" /> // запятая тут не нужна
       <Feedback />
    </React.Fragment> 
)
```

Запись:

```
<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
```

аналогична (тоже самое что):

```
<></>
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что кроме React было бы неплохо ещё и JavaScript изучить.

Когда вы пишите конструкцию вида `(a, b)` - вы используете оператор "запятая", который во всех Си-подобных языках возвращает последний аргумент.

Чтобы вернуть несколько элементов - вам нужен контейнер. React в качестве контейнера предлагает использовать [фрагмент](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html): `<>a b</>`.